# ip_forward=1 in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot fails

Tags: 20.04, routing, ip-forward

I have Ubuntu 20.04 configured as a router with nftables and frr (ospf configured) installed.
I have configured two interfaces (ens33 and ens34) in different networks,
forwarding is configured in /etc/sysctl.conf with net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 and also in
/etc/systemd/network/ens33.network

```
[Match]
Name=ens33

[Network]
IPForward=1
```

/etc/systemd/network/ens34.network

```
[Match]
Name=ens34

[Network]
IPForward=1
```

netplan file:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      mtu: 1300
      addresses:
      - 10.10.2.1/24
      gateway4: 10.10.2.254
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 10.10.3.1
        search:
        - management.int
    ens34:
      mtu: 1300
      addresses:
      - 10.10.20.254/24
      nameservers: {}
  bridges:
    br0:
      mtu: 1300
      addresses:
      - 10.10.3.22/32
      nameservers: {}
```

After command "systemctl -p" everything goes fine but after reboot ip forward is disabled (output of: sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward is: net.ipv4.ip_forward=0)

Comment: so, this looks like systemd-networkd rather than a netplan front end implementation. All I can say is, that it works for me and I do not have any `IPForward=1` in any of my `/etc/systemd/network/*.network files on my new, still in test, server/router/gateway. I am not using netplan either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `netplan` is generating the configuration, it will write a file for each interface to `/run/systemd/network/` in a format: `10-netplan-{interface}.network`. After that the `systemd-networkd` will apply the configuration. 
`systemd-networkd` will find configuration files in `/run/...` and your config files in `/etc/...` and it will precess them in lexical order.
From [www.freedesktop.org/.../systemd.network.html](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html):

> All configuration files are collectively sorted and processed in lexical order, regardless of the directories in which they live. However, files with identical filenames replace each other.

> **[Match] Section Options**
> The network file contains a [Match] section, which determines if a given network file may be applied to a given device; and a [Network] section specifying how the device should be configured. The first (in lexical order) of the network files that matches a given device is applied, all later files are ignored**, even if they match as well.

So now you can see that the `IPForward` option will never be applied.

Now you need to focus your troubleshooting on sysctl.conf

From [www.freedesktop.org/.../sysctl.d.html](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sysctl.d.html):

> **Configuration Directories and Precedence**
> Configuration files are read from directories in /etc/, /run/, /usr/local/lib/, and /usr/lib/, in order of precedence, as listed in the SYNOPSIS section above. Files must have the ".conf" extension. Files in /etc/ override files with the same name in /run/, /usr/local/lib/, and /usr/lib/. Files in /run/ override files with the same name under /usr/.
>
> All configuration files are sorted by their filename in lexicographic order, regardless of which of the directories they reside in. **If multiple files specify the same option, the entry in the file with the lexicographically latest name will take precedence**. Thus, the configuration in a certain file may either be replaced completely (by placing a file with the same name in a directory with higher priority), or individual settings might be changed (by specifying additional settings in a file with a different name that is ordered later).

---

**EDIT:**
It is possible that there are application which will override the `sysctl.conf`
For example `ufw` firewall configuration in `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf` might have line such as `net/ipv4/ip_forward=0` which would take precedence over `/etc/sysctl.conf`. It is not default configuration though, and it would have to be configured manually.

Comment: OK, I have configured net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 in /etc/sysctl.conf wchich takes precedence over all files, also I have configured same configuration before in other machine and there it works... still working on this

Comment: @Helngard /etc/sysctl.conf doesn't necessarily take precedence over all files. It does only when the file names are the same. I have provided you all the information, but I cannot troubleshoot it for you. If you that is what you are looking for, you should ask in forums.

Answer (score 0):

Create file `/etc/sysctl.d/99-forward.conf` with

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and reboot the OS.